# Plotting 3x3 until some points left out

Tags: plotting

I am to plot a bunch of numbers in a 3 by 3 manner.

However, some has 35 data line so when my code goes up to loop number 11 -> i.e. number of data plotted is 33, there is 2 remaining.

I wanted it to plot the remaining points into the last group.

How can I do that?

Data included [here](http://pastebin.com/BvtDB2Zp)

Edit: Images here

[image: There is an example here that after 11 rounds, there is still 2 points left. What I wanted is the remaining 2 points to be inserted into the last loop]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of input and desired output. It is not clear what are you after.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this ? I am not sure to have understood correctly

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, 35];

newlist = 
  Flatten@Append[list, 
      Table[Null, Ceiling[Length@#, 3] - Length[#]]] &@list;
Manipulate[ListPlot[Take[newlist, 3*t]], {t, 1, Length@newlist/3, 1}]
```